# Create initial Solution Python for Genetic Algorithms

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures

Please help to create an **initial_solution** Variable with condition below:

Struture

```
population_list = {"LHS":[], "RHS": []}
```

Number of Dictionary Element = `population_size = 20`

For each `population_list` element`"LHS"` and `"RHS"` elements.

For `"LHS"`, has both `job_count = 10`elements, Each element length sactify a list:

```
max_sublot = [3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 5]
```

Its value is an random value [0,1) rounded 2 decimals.

For the `"RHS"` has total `max_sublot * mc_op` elements.

```
max_sublot = [3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 5]
mc_op = [6, 14, 8, 5, 6, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2]
```

Each element length = 4, 1 value is `random of range job_count`, 2 is radom according to each value of `max_sublot`, 3 is a random of range `operation_count = 10`, 4 is radom according to each value of `mc_op`

That is an presentation for initial solution of GA, as photos below:
[image]
[image]

Could you please adive the suitable data struture for it, as my oppinion, that will be like that:
[image]

```
import numpy as np

population_size = 20
job_count = 10
operation_count = 10
max_sublot = [3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 5]
mc_op = [6, 14, 8, 5, 6, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2]

class Population_list(object):
    def __init__(self, LHS, RHS):
        self.LHS = LHS
        self.RHS = RHS

population_list = {"LHS":[], "RHS": []}
for i in range (population_size):
    for j in range(job_count):
        for s in max_sublot:
            lhs_random_num = list(np.random.random())
            population_list.update("LHS")
print(population_list)
```

Comment: Hi Khai, really trying to help you here but I cant understand your problem. What is it that you are trying to achieve? What are all those specifications ?

Comment: Hi Rafael, I try to create an Variable named population_list. That is a radom value, but base on restricted condition.

Comment: It has 20 elements ( equal population_size), each element has LHS and RHS part

Comment: For LHS, it has 10 elements, (equal job_count), the length of each element reflect in max_sublot List

Comment: Hmm I get now !

Comment: Value is a random from [0,1]

Comment: For LHS, it has sum of max_sublot * mc_op elements,  the length of each element is 4

Comment: Help me the RHS should not repeate

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
population_size = 20
job_count = 10
operation_count = 10
max_sublot = [3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 7, 9, 3, 5]
mc_op = [6, 14, 8, 5, 6, 9, 4, 6, 7, 2]
import numpy as np

def gen_population(population_size, max_sublot, mc_op, job_count):
    return tuple({'LHS': [gen_lhs(length) for length in max_sublot],
                  'RHS': gen_rhs(np.dot(max_sublot, mc_op), job_count, max_sublot, 10, mc_op)} for _ in range(population_size))


def gen_lhs(length):
    return [round(np.random.uniform(0,1),2) for _ in range(length)]

def gen_rhs(length, job_count, max_sublot, operation_count, mc_op):
    ret = []
    for i in range(length):
        new = []
        new.append(np.random.randint(job_count))
        new.append(np.random.choice(max_sublot))
        new.append(np.random.randint(operation_count))
        new.append(np.random.choice(mc_op))
        ret.append(new)
    return ret

gen_population(population_size, max_sublot, mc_op, job_count)
```

Comment: The LHS output is correct as above, but the RHS is not correct, the length should be equal sum of max_sublot * mc_op, and defined value random of value 2, and 4 should a range of each element of the List max_sublot and mc_op respectively, not the whole list

Comment: What do you mean by `max_sublot * mc_op` ? these are both lists, how do you multiply one list for another ?

Comment: For example, first element RHS can be [0, 2, 7,5], but not [0, 3, 7, 6] cause max_sublot[0] is 3 and mc_op[0] is 6

Comment: max_sublot * mc_op of this one equal 329 = 3*6 + 5*14...+ 5*2

Comment: So change `len(max_sublot) * len(mc_op)` for  `np.dot(max_sublot, mc_op)` in `gen_rhs` arguments

Comment: That's fine, so could you help to advise the way to get a correct random value of RHS for index 2 and 4?

Comment: Can you explain better the logic behind these numbers at index 2 and 4? gonna go sleep now, cant you catch up from there? ;) if not ill help tomorrow

Comment: index 1 is job#, 2 is sublot# of this job, 3 is operation# of this job, 4 is assigned machine# for this job.

Comment: 1 job can have many sublot#, but the maximum is describle in `max_sublot` List, the index of `max_sublot` List is job

Comment: For example, job 0 max sublot is 3, so that we can assign sublot: 0, 1, 2 only. Cannot 3, 4...

Comment: That is the same for index 4, for each operation have only scare resources machines available  in `mc_op`, for example operation 1 has 6 mc available, so that it can 0, 1 ..5, cannot 6 or 7